# Error in developing a database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I made an Android Database project. the code is:

```
package ir.applinkfinder.sqlite;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "student.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";

public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
public static final String COL_4 = "MARKS";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,  1);
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
}    
public boolean insertData(String name, String surname, String marks){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,name); // put(column name which you want to insert data, value itself)
    contentValues.put(COL_3,surname);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,marks);

    long MyResult = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues); 

    if( MyResult == -1 )
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

But the error is "error: class, interface, or enum expected + android studio database" which is related to the insertData method, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please provide the complete stacktrace

Comment: Or compile error in this case; but no longer necessary. As it is a simple typo. Something you kinda should not need to ask other people for help. If such things are giving you that hard of a time; sorry, then writing android apps talking to databases is most likely to completely overburden you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a stray `}` character above the `insertData` method, remove it.